# Set the current click row background color

Tags: jquery, css

How can I change the background color only to those rows that clicked, in the below code it does not clear the previous row clicked background color.

```
var tr = $('#webgrid_id').find('tr');
    tr.bind('click', function (event) {
        $("tr").click(function () { $(this).css('background', 'yellow'); });
});
```

[image]

Comment: keep a variable of the row that is clicked. On new click, clear out the row that's stored in the variable, then replace the variable with the new row

Comment: Thanks all and I can only select one answer and I wish could do multiple select answers, all answers are GREAT :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/12mze843/2/)**

You could simplify it by using class

```
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
```

<sub>Add the above to `<style>` or CSS file</sub>

---

```
$('#webgrid_id').on('click','tr',function () {
    $('tr.yellow').removeClass('yellow'); 
    $(this).addClass('yellow'); 
});
```

OR as *@A. Wolff* suggests refer this (more optimized and improved): http://jsfiddle.net/12mze843/1/

Also, I see a `click` event inside bind - there is no need to nesting these events.

Comment: have you tested your code? so when click on the row it get yellow background and when i click on a different row the previous row is not cleared

Comment: @A.Wolff, added your suggestion to my answer. Still getting used to using `add()` :P. Thanks for the suggestion. You can remove your suggestion from my answer if you don't feel its right.

Comment: it working fine until if i change to page 2 and click on the row then it did not change the background color

Comment: yes I did get the updated code and as I said when I go to page 2 and try to click it does not do anything and go back to page 1 it did no do anything either so it screwed up once I go to different page.

Comment: Can you post your whole html in a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var tr = $('#webgrid_id').find('tr');
tr.bind('click', function(event) {
  $(this).css('background', 'yellow')
    .siblings("tr").css('background', '#fff');
});
```

```css
tr td {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table id="webgrid_id">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```js
var tr = $('#webgrid_id').find('tr');

    tr.bind('click', function (event) {
        tr.css('background','');
        $("tr").click(function () { 
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="webgrid_id">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save the previously clicked row in a variable and change it's back color to the old color when another row is clicked, like this:

```
var prevTr = null;
var tr = $('#webgrid_id').find('tr');
prevTr = tr;
tr.bind('click', function (event) {
    $("tr").click(function () { 
   $(this).css('background', 'yellow'); 
   $(prevTr).css('background', 'white'); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give a class to it and change this class when clicking

```
$("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.inYellow{background-color:yellow;}</style>");

$("tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("inYellow");
});
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9e9hry0e/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/4mf61j5s/1/

```
$('body').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
      $('#webgrid_id tr').removeClass('clickedrow');//clear all highlights
      $(this).toggleClass('clickedrow'); 
 });
```

And you need to have this style:

```
<style>
     .clickedrow {background-color:yellow;}
</style>
```